# Edit same property of all selected objects at once?

Tags: modifiers, properties

How can I edit the same property on all selected objects at once? For example, if I select 5 mesh objects and I want to lock rotation x or I have selected 20 curves and want to edit 'Preview U resolution' of all of them at once or change the bevel depth of all of them to 2. And if they have same modifier can we edit modifier's properties at once?